# Camel and Netty: client - intermediary app - server

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I am using Camel and Netty to set up a scenario where a client connects to a server with an application in between (just a dummy app called Router).

SocketClient connects to Router (port 53379) and Router connects Server (port 53383). Problem is that the packet never reaches the server (it does reach the Router though, I debugged that with a processor).

If I connect SocketClient to Server it works fine.

Any help is appreciated.

### Complete source

Router:

```
public class Router {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
        registry.put("ByteArrayEncoder", new ByteArrayEncoder());
        registry.put("ByteArrayDecoder", new ByteArrayDecoder());
        
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
        
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("netty4:tcp://localhost:53379?encoders=#ByteArrayEncoder&"
                        + "decoders=#ByteArrayDecoder"
                        + "&sync=true"
                        + "&keepAlive=true")
                .to("netty4:tcp://localhost:53383?encoders=#ByteArrayEncoder&"
                        + "decoders=#ByteArrayDecoder"
                        + "&sync=true"
                        + "&keepAlive=true");               
            }
        });

        context.start();
        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
        registry.put("ByteArrayEncoder", new ByteArrayEncoder());
        registry.put("ByteArrayDecoder", new ByteArrayDecoder());
        
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
        
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("netty4:tcp://localhost:53383?encoders=#ByteArrayEncoder&"
                        + "decoders=#ByteArrayDecoder"
                        + "&sync=true"
                        + "&keepAlive=true")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        Message message = exchange.getIn();
                        System.out.println("from este_stub: " + message.getBody());
                        exchange.setOut(message);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        context.start();
        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class SocketClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 53379);
        OutputStream simOutStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream simInStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());        
        
        byte[] arr = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        simOutStream.write(arr, 0, arr.length);
        simOutStream.flush();
        
        
        byte[] resp = new byte[5];
        simInStream.read(resp, 0, resp.length);
        for(byte ar : resp)
            System.out.print(ar);
        
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the code you shared gives the following error in the Router class `io.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: io.netty.handler.codec.bytes.ByteArrayDecoder is not a @Sharable handler, so can't be added or removed multiple times.`

As the exception says, the **ByteArrayDecoder** as well as **ByteArrayEncoder** are not sharable handlers and thus the reason for the error. From the javadoc of Sharable, it clearly states that

> Indicates that the same instance of the annotated ChannelHandler can be added to one or more ChannelPipeline multiple times without a race condition. If this annotation is not specified, you have to create a new handler instance every time you add it to a pipeline because it has unshared state such as member variables.

The camel documentation for netty4 also states this at [Camel netty4](http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html)

as follows :

> If your encoders or decoders is not shareable (eg they have the @Shareable class annotation), then your encoder/decoder must implement the org.apache.camel.component.netty.ChannelHandlerFactory interface, and return a new instance in the newChannelHandler method. This is to ensure the encoder/decoder can safely be used. If this is not the case, then the Netty component will log a WARN when
>   an endpoint is created.
>   The Netty component offers a org.apache.camel.component.netty.ChannelHandlerFactories factory class, that has a number of commonly used methods.

So your problem is resolved by using some custom encoder and decoder implementing ChannelHandlerFactory and overriding the newChannelHandler as shown below :

public class CustomByteArrayDecoder implements ChannelHandlerFactory {

```
@Override
public void handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {

}

@Override
public void handlerRemoved(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {

}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {

}

@Override
public ChannelHandler newChannelHandler() {
    return new ByteArrayDecoder();
}
```

and similarly for the encoder as well . Then making proper changes in the Router and Server as following:

```
SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
registry.put("ByteArrayEncoder", new CustomByteArrayEncoder());
registry.put("ByteArrayDecoder", new CustomByteArrayDecoder());
```

Comment: Thank you! As soon as you said exception I noticed I had forgotten to setup the log4j.properties file. Btw, implementing ChannelFactory only required the newChannelHandler() method.

Comment: Thats great. Also do check the Camel netty4 documentation as they have mentioned some important options while configuring the endpoints.